# Revert minify enabled and proguard effect on decompiled apk

Tags: java, android, apk

I have developed an application before and Now I can't find my application source code.
I want to make some changes to my application.

Now I just have my **keystore(jks file)** which I have use it to sign my application before.
I use [online Apk Decompiler](http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk) to **decompile** my application but It does not give my desired result.
I need it to edit my codes and give it to the customer but It gives me code preview like below with Incomprehensible class and method names.

> **My decompiled APK folders directory**

[image: folder direcotory]

> **My Code Preview**

[image: Code preview]

I know that this problem is for setting **minify enabled** to true for release mode in gradle .

Is there any way to revert decompiled code to **understandable code** or revert it with **keystore** or decompile application apk file with understandable source code?

I really need to decompile this apk and do some changes on it .
Specially application source files.

**Any help will be appreciated :)**

Answer (score 7):

Seems to me you're trying to do some reverse engineering.
That's one of the points of proguard, to make this more difficult.

If you are the developer, see if you saved the mappings.txt file when you did the build. It's will show to what the obfuscated names refer to. Otherwise, no, there is no way to know what the names were before obfuscation without that file.